# JMeter-JDBC Connection error

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

While running an SQl query in JMeter using JDBC request, I'm getting:

`SQL ConnectionException:Cannot create Poolable Connectionfactory`

(`IO error:Network Adapter could not establish the connection`).

Installed `Oracle11g` in virtual machine.

Please give me solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The database is most likely not accessible through the network... check that the host is pingable, that the DB port is accessible, etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have [Oracle JDBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) somewhere in [JMeter Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Make sure you have configured network adapter in the virtual machine in [Bridge mode](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws4/doc/network_bridged_ws.html) (not "host-only", not "NAT") so the virtual machine would have its own IP address.
3. Make sure port 1521 (or whatever is used by Oracle) is not blocked by OS firewall. Check if you are able to connect to the port using i.e. [telnet client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731442(v=ws.11).aspx)
4. Add [JDBC Connection Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) test element and provide JDBC url of your Oracle instance along with credentials there.

See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter) guide to learn more about setting up JMeter for databases load testing